# Working with Cakephp and TinyMCE Editor

Tags: cakephp, tinymce

**I am using cakephp 2.3 version. I tried to get tinymce editor by reference of Helper TinyMCE for CakePHP 2 [http://bakery.cakephp.org/articles/galitul/2012/04/11/helper_tinymce_for_cakephp_2].**

At the end

> Error: The application is trying to load a file from the jquery-1 plugin

is showing. I cound solve this error. Please help me to solve this error.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Did you even attempt to Google? https://github.com/CakeDC/TinyMCE First result for 'cakephp tinymce'

Comment: While i am using  github.com/CakeDC/TinyMCE , i got the error "Declaration of TinyMCEHelper::beforeRender() should be compatible with Helper::beforeRender($viewFile) [APP/Plugin/TinyMCE/View/Helper/TinyMCEHelper.php, line 95]"

Comment: This is an issue with PHP 5.4 being strict about inherited method parameters. I have encountered a similar issue on the utils plugin, I would raise an issue on Github and it should get fixed.

Answer (score 2):

You really shouldn't need a plugin for this as TinyMCE is a plugin. Just include TinyMCE in your template and in your JavaScript attach it to textareas that require the editor. I do this using the jQuery version of TinyMCE and attach it to any textarea with the class "wysiwyg" (which I add to the relevant form elements.